# Consuming an ASP.NET web service with jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a jquery ajax function that is consuming an ASP.NET xml web service, as shown in the code below.

The code is successful up to a point (i.e. "DoSomething" does what it is supposed to do) but it does not seem to enter the "success" function (i.e. the alert does not show).

Why?

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://myServer/Service1.asmx/DoSomething",
        data: "FirstName=AN&Surname=Other&EmailAddress=another@somewhere.com",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("test");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check your console for errors.

Comment: try adding `error: function()...` and seeing what error you're getting

Comment: cross domain issue? Also, I believe your dataType should be xml

Comment: Seeing the DoSomething method would help. Also as others have pointed out the error: function will give you more information. Finally I tend to use JSON.stringify() for my data property... personal preference though

Answer (score 1):

i think this the way you should call the method

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/Service1.asmx/DoSomething",
    data: {FirstName:"AN",Surname:"Other",EmailAddress:"another@somewhere.com"},
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("test");
    }
});
```

and in the method

```
[WebMethod]
public void dosomething(string FirstName,string Surname,string EmailAddress)
{

//do process
}
```

hope this helps you

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the quotes on the line beginning... data:

Also, I can't shorten the url value, I need the full http:// address as the web service is hosted remotely

Comment: @cymorg if the request is cross domain then CORS will have to be set up.